# why does having a bad cold make thinking harder

Tags: common-cold, concentration, mental-exhaustion, brain-fog

I find when I have a bad cold and talking to other people it isn't just me, that thinking feels like really hard work and the simplest job becomes really tricky.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well once I woke up that was easy to find

> These short-term declines stem from temporary changes in the brain
>   rather than cold or flu symptoms themselves, he said. Seasonal viruses
>   reduce mental alertness by interfering with neurotransmitters such as
>   noradrenaline, associated with reaction times.

https://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/health-and-fitness/health/why-brain-fog-from-the-common-cold-isnt-all-in-your-head/article36812938/

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by excessive energy used to defeat the viruses or adverse bacteria-the triggers of cold and flu. Your body lacks enough energy to operate the physical activity, which affects the oxygen transmitting to your brain, so you could feel tired or fatigue to think or finish a simple motion. Also, cold medicines commonly have certain side effects such as drowsiness, which can intensify the feeling of fatigue. 
Sleeping and doing exercise help to produce more energy, which can shorten the time of treatment and enhance the immunity.

Comment: Citations please? This sounds like some good speculation but answers here need to be supported with evidence - speculation and intuition can be extremely misleading, especially when involving the brain.